# Unable to track down a math font

Tags: fonts, mathcal

I'm trying to find the mathematical font of the `\mathcal T` in the following excerpt:

[image]

It is taken from https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Freyd+cover, and trying to compile locally the tex source I don't get the same result so I guess it is some MathJaX magic. Do you any of you recognize the font?

Comment: the font menu of your browser would report that as DejaVu Math TeX Gyre

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, there was a CSS style sheet with that info somewhere, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the font menu of your browser would report that as DejaVu Math TeX Gyre

[image]